# Why does "foo()" gets selfinvoked when assigned to addEventListener method

Tags: javascript, function

```
function foo() {
    console.log("clicked");
}

element.addEventListener("click", foo());
```

Why does `foo()` gets selfinvoked when the script loads and `foo` doesn't?
And what if I need to pass an argument to the function like so:

```
function foo(elem) {
    console.log(elem,"clicked");
}

element.addEventListener("click", foo("element"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the reference the the function, otherwise it will get called at the time that the event handler is binded. Try this:

```
element.addEventListener("click", foo);
```

If you need to pass parameters, wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
element.addEventListener("click", function(){
    foo("element")
});
```